# AttributeError: module 'ga' has no attribute 'select_mating_pool'

Tags: python-3.x

MY CODE:
parents = GA.select_mating_pool(population, fitness,
num_parents_mating)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\LENOVO\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\main.py", line 180, in 
parents = GA.select_mating_pool(population, fitness,
AttributeError: module 'ga' has no attribute 'select_mating_pool'

Comment: Is GA a class you wrote or something imported? We need more detail

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.